# Где в Drupal 7 прописывается viewport?

Tags: php, html, drupal

Впервые столкнулся с этим движком и в упор не понимаю, в каком месте и как прописать viewport. Привычного шаблона header я не нахожу.

Этот код не помогает, вставлял в templates.php:

```html
function THEMENAME_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
  $head_elements['chrome_frame'] = array(
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => array('http-equiv' => 'X-UA-Compatible', 'content' => 'IE=edge,chrome=1'),
    '#weight' => -1001,
  );

  $head_elements['device_width'] = array(
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => array('name' => 'viewport', 'content' => 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'),
  );
}
```

Очень надеюсь на помощь.

Comment: вы ответ принимать собираетесь?

Answer (score 1):

Обычно это делается в шаблоне html.tpl.php. В файле templates.php это делается тогда, когда есть какие-либо определенные условия вставки тега.

Пример html.tpl.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
<?php print $head; ?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" /-->
<?php print $styles; ?>
<?php print $scripts; ?>

</head>
<body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?>>
    <?php print $page_top; ?>
    <?php print $page; ?>
    <?php print $page_bottom; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Но сделаем и в шаблонизаторе при [помощи хука](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_html_head_alter/7.x) (это разместить в /sites/all/themes/имятемы/template.php где и обязана быть ваша тема), пример:

```
function имятемыобязательно_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
    $head_elements['viewport'] = Array
        (
            '#type' => 'html_tag',
            '#tag' => 'meta',
            '#attributes' => Array
                (
                    'name' => 'viewport',
                    'content' => 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'
                ),

            '#weight' => -500
        );
}
```

Comment: теперь буду знать, к кому с вопросами по D7 обращаться))